# What happens to the sea of electrons when a metal melts/boils?

Tags: metal, intermolecular-forces, boiling-point, melting-point

I was taught about metallic solids with the sea of electrons model. My question is how does the sea of electrons function when metal turns into a liquid and a gas. The way I see a liquid is intermolecular forces being constantly formed and broken between particles, but metallic bonds are different in how they are attractions between shared, mobile electrons and nuclei. I can't visualize how particles moving faster have less attraction force with the electrons when they are surrounded by them at all times. From [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Chemical_Bonding/Fundamentals_of_Chemical_Bonding/Metallic_Bonding), it tells me that when a metal melts, the bonds are "loosened" and when it boils, they "break". How does that even work? Is something happening to the sea of electrons that results in some metallic bonds breaking in molten metals and all metallic bonds breaking in gases? In a gas, as the particles get further apart, I doubt the sea of electrons is expanding to fit the entire volume of the gas, because, at that point, it would just be cations and electrons, not atoms, so do the electrons "relocalize" to an ion's valence shell when they can no longer be attracted to multiple atoms?

Comment: It seems that you have somehow the picture except for the fact that a metal in gas phase isn't a metal anymore, that is there is not that sea of electron anymore. Until the phase is the melt, you are in presence of a loose sea,as you said. All is a balance between the kinetic energy of the atoms and the attraction. In such a sense is not different than melting and eventually boiling an ionic or covalent compound. I think this comment should suffice.

Comment: Liquid metals are (as far as I know) all metallic - they have the 'sea' of electrons, just not in Bloch states any more. Silicon and germanium, semiconductors as solids, become metallic in the liquid phase (and go from 4-fold coordinated in the solid to 8- to 12-fold coordinated in the liquid, the main reason the liquid is denser than the solid).